# Полиморфизм в Java

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

Добрый вечер. Изучая полиморфизм в Java натолкнулся на такой пример:

```
  class A {
    void m1(A a) {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void m1(B b) {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    void m1(B c) {
        System.out.print("C");
    }
}

class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A c1 = new C();
        c1.m1(new B());
    }
}
```

И возник вопрос почему ответ в данной программе А ? Получается, что в данной строчке

```
A c1 = new C();
```

происходит процесс полиморфизма и по правилам должен вызываться метод m1 класса С (который не переопределен , а перегружен и в качестве параметра принимает любую переменную типа В). Подскажите что в моих рассуждениях не так ? (Ведь ответ вроде должен быть С)
И еще один пример :

```
public void go() {
   А param = new A();
   Object obj = getObject(A);
}

  public Object getObject(Object o) {
   return o;
}
```

Скажите , почему если в строчке :

```
 Object obj = getObject(A);
```

Поменять Object на A, то произойдет ошибка ? Если параметр метода указан как Object, то при вызове функции getObject с аргументом A он будет приводиться к Object? Получается, что если возвращаемое значения метода указано как Object, то тип A будет приводиться к Object ? Если это так, то объясните пожалуйста как это происходит, а если нет, то скажите что происходит на самом деле ?

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: "Во втором примере у вас разница между статическим типом (известным во время компиляции), и динамическим (настоящим типом объекта во время выполнения).В Java логика такова: функция getObject декларирует, что вернёт объект типа Object, компилятор не «подглядывает» в реализацию (на это есть свои причины) и не знает, что на самом деле вернётся экземпляр типа A. Поэтому он и отказывается компилировать код A obj = getObject(param)."

Скажите, что значит компилятор не «подглядывает» в реализацию ? Этот момент немного не понял.

Comment: @Drylozav: Компилятор не знает, что если передать в `getObject` объект типа `A`, то и вернётся тоже объект типа `A`. Всё, что он учитывает при анализе — это то, что возвращаемый тип у `getObject` — `Object`, а значит, в коде `A a = getObject(new A());` он не сможет гарантировать, что возвращённый объект будет точно типа `A`. Поэтому он откажется такое компилировать.

Comment: Скажите, а где про это можно почитать. А то я не знаю, что мне нужно для этой информации искать.

Comment: @Drylozav: Хороший вопрос. По идее, так работает ООП везде, так что по идее найдите книгу по ООП просто. (Подсказать не могу, учился на собственном опыте.)

Смотрите, тут всё логично, вы только должны (1) понимать отличие статического типа от динамического, (2) понимать, что компилятор оперирует лишь статическими типами, (3) понимать, что объект производного класса может всегда подменить собой объект базового, так как он _является_ разновидностью базового.

Comment: Хочу узнать о динамических типах в Java. Ввожу в Google, ни одного нормального сайта не выдало. Может я не то вбил ? Хотел информацию узнать.

Comment: @Drylozav: Правильная ссылка для поиска такая: <https://www.google.com/search?q=java+runtime+vs+compile+time+type>.

Comment: @Drylozav, насколько помню в "Философия Java" Б. Эккеля хорошо описано.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

По поводу первого примера: для того, чтобы функция производного класса считалась полиморфным вариантом функции базового класса, у них должны совпадать не только имена, но и типы аргументов. Поскольку `A::m1` и `B::m1` имеют *разные* типы аргументов (`A` и `B` соответственно), эти две функции считаются всего лишь *перегрузкой* имени `m1` (так же как оператор + может применяться и к целым числам, и к числам с плавающей запятой, просто две несвязанные функции названы одинаково), и выбор между ними производится на этапе компиляции.

Специалист сказал бы, что в Java нет ко/контравариантности по аргументам при полиморфизме.

В вашем случае статический тип переменной `c1` есть `A`, у `A` будет вызвана функция `A::m1`, поскольку динамический тип `B`, как мы выяснили, *не* перекрывает полиморфно эту функцию.

Во втором примере у вас разница между статическим типом (известным во время компиляции), и динамическим (настоящим типом объекта во время выполнения). Вы языках со слабой типизацией наподобие PHP или Javascript'а разницы нет, но в Java логика такова: функция `getObject` декларирует, что вернёт объект типа `Object`, компилятор не «подглядывает» в реализацию (на это есть [свои причины](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) и не знает, что на самом деле вернётся экземпляр типа `A`. Поэтому он и отказывается компилировать код `A obj = getObject(param)`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. По поводу второго примера я понял. А вот с полиморфизмом не очень. Почему для подходящего варианта компилятор выбирает метод m1 класса А ? Ведь его сигнатура не подходит. Я имею в виду, что мы передаем в качестве аргумента параметр new B(), а у метода m1 класса А в качестве параметра метода принимается переменная "а" с типом класса А.

Comment: @Drylozav, потому что переменная c1 имеет тип A и компилятор ищет подходящий метод m1 именно в этом классе и находит только m1(A). Он не видит методов производных от A классов даже не смотря на то, что c1 ссылается на объект класса C. Все дело в типе самой ссылки, а не в реальном типе объекта. Метод m1(B) не замещает метод m1(A), так как у них разные сигнатуры (отличаются списки параметров), как уже сказал @VladD.

Comment: а по какому принципу компилятор решил , что нужно выбирать именно этот метод из класса А ? Почему не выдал ошибки что метода с такой сигнатурой не существует ? Или он как то неявно преобразовал тип параметра метода ?

Comment: Давайте посмотрим на ваш код глазами компилятора. Он видит в классе A метод m1(A). Он просматривает потомков класса A и не видит в них ни одного метода с такой же сигнатурой (методы m1(B) из классов B и C не являются полиморфными переопределениеми m1(A) так как у них отличаются сигнатуры). Он понимает, что вызовы метода m1(A) он может разрешать на этапе компиляции, что и делает. В строчке c1.m1(new B()) он видит вызов m1 из класса A (так как с1 объявлен как объект класса A, метод A.m1 не переопределён ни в одном из потомков, а new B() - потомок класса A).

Comment: А что тогда будет в строчке m1(A a), если туда поступает параметр new B()?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, не будет ли переданный объект класса B рассматриваться как объект класса A? Будет. В методе m1(A) вы не сможете вызвать ни одного метода класса B, которые не определены в классе A, так как на этапе компиляции неизвестно, что вы именно объект B туда передаёте. Однако, на этапе выполнения виртуальная машина будет учитывать переопределение методов. Например, если бы в методе m1(A) вы вызывали какой-то метод, которые переопределён в B (полиморфно переопределён, т. е. имеет точно такую же сигнатуру), то вызвался бы именно метод из класса B.

Comment: Пример:

    class A {
        public void m1(A a) {
            a.print();
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.print("A");
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        public void m1(B b) {
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.print("B");
        }
    }

    A c1 = new B();
    c1.m1(new B());

В этом случае выведется B.

Comment: @Drylozav: `A::m1(new B())` вызывается потому, что `B` _является_ `A`. Компилятор видит выражение типа `B` (`new B()`), он думает: но ведь `B` — это и `A` тоже, значит, функция вызывается правильно.

Полиморфизм выражает отношение _is a_: `Dog extends Animal` означает, что собака _является_ животным, и везде, где ожидается животное, собака подойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Override?

```
class C extends B {

    @Override
    void m1(B c) {
        System.out.print("C");
    }
}
```

И будет то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Не вводите человека в заблуждение. Лучше почитайте [документацию][1]. Аннотация `@Override` предназначена для генерации ошибок компиляции, если помеченный ей метод не переопределяет метод из класса-родителя.

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: @fori1ton, спасибо, документация по BufferedReader очень помогла

Comment: @Suvitruf, не за что. Если захотите почитать именно доки по Override, обратитесь [сюда][1].

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html