# Наследование и полиморфизм

Tags: java, наследование, объекты, полиморфизм

Есть два класса

```
public class CardAction {
  public void doPayment(double amountPayment) {
    System.out.println("complete from debt card");
  }
}

public class CreditCardAction extends CardAction {
  public boolean checkCreditLimit() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void doPayment(double amountPayment) { 
    System.out.println("complete from credit card");
  }
}
```

Почему, при таком создании объекта, доступ есть только к переопределенным методам в подклассе, а к новым (неполиморфным) методам доступа нету?

```
CardAction dc2 = new CreditCardAction();
```

Comment: Птмчт в этом суть полиморфизма?)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491263/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B2-java  ...... ответ раз .......http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/279518/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B2-java ..... ответ два...... и т.д. ....может всеже в поиске посмотрите?))

Comment: потому что у вас переменная класса _CardAction_, а в классе _CardAction_ есть только метод _doPayment_, было бы странно, если бы в нем вдруг появился еще какой-то метод

Comment: пиши пример нового метода

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян, так в примере ж есть уже _checkCreditLimit_

Comment: @Grundy но вызывается ведь метод из подкласса. 
Но я уже разобрался с этим, это все полиморфизм и "позднее связывание".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Потому что их (неполиморфных методов) может и не быть

#### ...и поэтому это небезопасно (с т. з. type safety)

Присваивая значение в переменную базового для него типа (т. н. **up-cast**, обобщающий каст, преобразование в супертип/базовый тип), вы ограничиваете свои возможности по работе с ним **только тем, что есть в базовом типе**. На уровне языка вы **теряете** информацию о том, какой тип был у исходного значения (во время выполнения она всё равно есть, но об этом далее), у вас значение **базового типа**. Что **реально** внутри него, вас интересовать там не должно.

Взамен вы получаете возможность работать со значением любого подходящего к указанному типа, даже того, о котором на момент разработки вы можете даже не знать. К примеру, для вашей библиотеки пользователь может реализовать собственный класс и передавать его объекты в ваш код. Без вашего участия в его продукте.

Это относится не только к классам и их **базовым** (по наследованию) классам, но и к классам и реализуемым ими **интерфейсам**. Интерфейсы же тоже являются типами, правда, в чистом виде они не существуют вовсе, но определяют **общие черты** всех подходящих к ним типов: посему, безопасно пользоваться у значения типа интерфейса можно только этими самыми **общими чертами**.

В этом есть смысл, если вспомнить, какие ошибки проверяемая компилятором типизация задумана избегать: в основном это ошибки получения в некотором месте значения, не обладающего некими требуемыми там **возможностями**. Возможности определяет **тип переменной**. Компилятор пробует **доказать**, что эти возможности есть, и если этого сделать не может, сообщает вам, как место потенциальной ошибки.

---

Конкретно в Java есть down-casting, преобразование из более общего типа в более конкретный, но **только явное**, что уже намекает на то, что это действие опасное и может закончиться **ошибкой** (`ClassCastException`).

Но подобное есть не везде и им стоит пользоваться только в крайних случаях.

Comment: На практике такое объявление используется?  

    CardAction dc2 = new CreditCardAction();

Comment: @jisecayeyo большого смысла в этом я не вижу, поскольку всюду, где вы работаете с более общим типом, вы можете указать именно его и при передаче объекта туда конкретного типа произойдёт неявный upcast до нужного. Но такой код я встречал. Это мог быть результат рефакторинга с заменой типов, например.

Answer (score -1):

Вы создаете объект класса `CardAction` у которого нет метода   `checkCreditLimit()`. Чтобы вызвать этот метод, вы должны создавать объект класса `CreditCardAction`

```
CreditCardAction dc2 = new CreditCardAction();
dc2.checkCreditLimit();
```

Comment: создает ТС как раз `CreditCardAction`, а присваивает его переменной базового типа `CardAction`