# Не могу понять полиморфный вызов метода

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

У меня есть класс `Pair`:

```
public class Pair {
   public void getObject(Object o){
       System.out.println("Text from Pair");}
 }
```

От него наследуется класс `Detail`, у которого есть такой же метод, но он принимает объект другого типа:

```
public class Detail extends Pair {
  public void getObject(Date o){
    System.out.println("Text from Detail");}
}
```

В `Main` у меня вот это:

```
Detail d = new Detail();
Pair p = d;
p.getObject(new Date());
```

И по сути должен исполняться полиморфный вызов метода, но для объекта `Detail` вызывается метод `getObject` с класса `Pair`, почему так? Как именно здесь работает вызов метода?

Comment: тут у тебя совсем другой идет метод ибо сигнатура другая....... полиморфно, это если бы сигнатура совпадала

Answer (score 5):

В java есть 3 поведения, относящиеся к Вашей теме:

- overriding (официальная документация [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html))
- overloading (официальная документация [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) - секция "Overloading Methods")
- hiding (официальная документация [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html))

Поскольку в документации сказано, что:

> The overriding method has the same name, number and type of
>   parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides. An
>   overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by
>   the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant return type.

и в Вашем случае у Вас нарушено правило `number and type of parameters`, то получается это не override. В то же время, касательно overload написано следующее:

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java
>   can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This
>   means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have
>   different parameter lists (there are some qualifications to this that
>   will be discussed in the lesson titled "Interfaces and Inheritance").

Что относится именно к Вашей ситуации.
Таким образом, вызывая метод по ссылке `Pair p` Вы будете вызывать метод класса `Pair`, не смотря на то, что фактически это объект `Detail`.

Кроме того, в java есть механизм отслеживания подобных недоразумений в виде `@Override` аннотации, пометив ей метод компилятор выдаст ошибку в случае, если это не override. В Вашем случае:

```
@Override
public void getObject(Date o){
    System.out.println("Text from Detail");}
```

Компилятор выдаст ошибку `"Method doesn't override method from its superclass"`.

Ну и в конце концов, чтобы добиться настоящего overrid'a в классе `Detail` метод должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public void getObject(Object o){
    System.out.println("Text from Detail");}
```

В таком случае Вы получите ожидаемый результат.

Надеюсь удалось подробно все объяснить. Удачи в дальнейшем изучении =).

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы функция производного класса считалась полиморфным вариантом функции базового класса, у них должны совпадать не только имена, но и типы аргументов. В вашем случае две функции считаются всего лишь перегрузкой имени `getObject`. И в `p.getObject(new Date());` происходит вызов класса `Pair`.

[похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/279518/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B2-java)

Comment: Вопрос был почему.

Comment: @Qwertiy нет там такого вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Что бы понять что происходит нужно уточнить несколько понятий:

1. Перезрузка. Вы можете иметь в одном классе 2 метода с одинаковыми именем но разными параметрами.
2. Переопределение. Необходимо полное совпадение типов входящих параметров.
3. Наследование. Предоставляет поля и методы родительского класса

*Это не определяния понятий перегрузка, переопределение и наследование а только некоторые моменты имеющие отношение к вопросу.*

В вашем случае объект `Detail` имеет два варианта метода `getObject`, один тот который вы определили явно прямо в классе : `public void getObject(Date o)`, и второй который он получил от родителя в результате наследования : `public void getObject(Object o)`.

Когда VM нужно определить какой метод вызывать, она смотрит какого типа параметр вы отправили в метод, и по типу этого параметра выбирает подходищий выриант перегрузки.

Следуя этой логике можно подумать что должен быть вызван метод с параметром типа `Date`. **Но вы делайте приведение типов**:

```
Detail d = new Detail();
Pair p = d; //Вот здесь. Это равнозначно Pair p = (Pair) d;
p.getObject(new Date());
```

А список методов для объекта всегда определяется по **типу указателя**. И так как тип указателя у вас теперь `Pair` а у него есть только один вариант этого метода то он и вызвался. Ну а так как он принимает `Object` то и `Date` "заглотил не морщась". И вызвался **единственный** имеющийся у `Pair` метод `getObject(Object)`.

Comment: Вот не совсем. Если в данном примере у `Pair` в качестве входного параметра поставить `Date` или у `Detail` поставить `Object` то выведется `"Text from Detail"`, а не `"Text from Pair"` не смотря на все эти типы указателей.......ради интереса поставь `Date` в `Pair` и `Object` в `Detail` - результат будет как у ТС, хотя по твоей логике влияло еще то, что `Object` заглотил `Date`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский нет вы не правильно поняли мое пояснение. То что Object заглотил Date имеется в виду что нет проблем с приведением типов. А логика моя указывает на то что список методов определяется по типу указателя и в случае перезрузки родительских методов это так же верно.